# Setting default values for existing DB records when updating schema with the Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database-schema, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to add the [Required] attribute to existing database records that contains *NULL* values, and where the database itself is autogenerated with Code First Migrations. The model schema update may look like this:

```
public class Product // BEFORE UPDATE
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Product // AFTER UPDATE
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]   // <---- Added
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I then run the commands

```
add-migration MakeColorRequired // Runs successfully
update-database                 // Crashes
```

The latter command crashes because it will not allow for an existing DB entry with the *color* element already set to *NULL* to become a required field, giving the error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Color', 
       table 'MySystem.dbo.Product'; 
       column does not allow nulls. 
       UPDATE fails.
```

Is there any way of overcoming this issue without dropping the database? Being able to set a new default value for all conflicting records would, for instance, work well in my scenario, but I have not yet found any manner of actually doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the migration to include a SQL statement to update all the records where that field is null to the new default value.

```
public override void Up() 
{ 
    Sql("UPDATE dbo.Product SET Color = '' WHERE Color IS NULL");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the default database value by editing the migration as follows:

```
public override void Up() 
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.Product ", "Color", c => c.String(nullable: false, defaultValue: ""));

}
```